# XSLT generates malformed path on chrome

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, xslt, web

I'm trying to generate some HTML from XML using XSLT. I have this subset of tags:

```
<IMG>
    <path>
        img/path.jpg
    </path>
...
</IMG>
```

The path of the image, once generated in the index.html file, includes the line feed and the indentation tabs! (for instance: src="img/pathToImg.jpg%0A%09%09%09")
This seems to happen in chrome. It works fine in Firefox and IE.
What could it be?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: XSD is a language for writing schemas against which XML documents can be validated.  It's not a transformation tool, so it's unlikely to be what you're using to generate your HTML.  Do you perhaps mean XSLT? Either way, show us the code that's generating the problematic HTML, along with sample input, as well as your sample output.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I meant XSLT! Anyway, I worked around the issue by removing spaces and indentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown us your XSLT, but often you can have XSLT strip out whitespace by using `normalize-space()`:

```
 <img src="{normalize-space(path)}" />
```

Comment: Just tried it and it worked! (Too late unfortunately, since we moved on to another project in my course)